# Axios removing the character 's' from get parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, get, query-string

I am working on react codebase in my workplace. Here all the axios get methods with a params object are removing the character 's' from the query parameters. Here's one of the axios calls

```
            sort_by: this.props.sort_by || "",
            order_by: this.props.order_by || "",
            vendor: this.props.vendor,
            status: JSON.stringify(this.props.status),
            per_page: this.state.per_page,
        };
        searchTerm && (params.search_term = searchTerm);

        source_url &&
            (await axios
                .get(source_url, { params })
                .then(async (response) => {})
```

These are the interceptors I have:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(async function (config) {
    NProgress.start();
    // @ts-ignore
    if (!!window.app_bridge_app) {
        // @ts-ignore
        return await getSessionToken(window.app_bridge_app) // requires an App Bridge instance
            .then((token) => {
                // append your request headers with an authenticated token
                config.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
                return config;
            });
    } else {
        config.headers["Authorization"] = ``;
        return config;
    }
});


axios.interceptors.response.use(
    function (response) {
        NProgress.done();
        !!response.data && !!response.data.success_message && toast.success(response.data.success_message);
        return response;
    }, function (error) {
        console.log('interceptor three error');``
        NProgress.done();
        if (!!error.response.data.errors) {
            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(error.response.data.errors)) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    toast.error(value);
                }, (+key > 4 ? (+key * 200) : (+ key - 1)));
            }
        } else {
            toast.error(!!error.response.data.error_message ? error.response.data.error_message : error.response.statusText);
        }

        return Promise.reject(error);
    });
```

I am sending two parameters 'sort_by' & 'status' & sometimes 'search_term' which has the character 's' in them. When I inspect the network tab I see the request url being:
`http://localhost:8000/api/metafield-resource/products?page=2&ort_by=title&order_by=asc&vendor=&tatu=[]&per_page=10`

You can see that all the 's' are being removed from the query params. It's not removing the 's' from the param values(ie: `status: 'ssabc'` becomes `tatu: 'ssabc'`). I can't find out what's the problem here. Hope to get you guys' help. Thanks!

Comment: Well that's bizarre. What version of Axios are you using?

Comment: No repro (using Axios 1.4.0) ~ https://jsfiddle.net/jubtv24y/

Comment: @Philisonstrike my axios version is 1.3.4

Comment: Still no repro ~ https://jsfiddle.net/8zb2xq9n/. Have you added any interceptors or `paramsSerializer` to your Axios instance?

Comment: @Philisonstrike I have two interceptors ```axios.interceptors.request.use(async function (config) {
    NProgress.start();
    if (!!window.app_bridge_app) {
        return await getSessionToken(window.app_bridge_app) // requires an App Bridge instance
            .then((token) => {
                config.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
                return config;
            });
    } else {
        config.headers["Authorization"] = ``;
        return config;
    }
});

```

Comment: Another is: ```axios.interceptors.response.use(
    function (response) {
        NProgress.done();
        !!response.data && !!response.data.success_message && toast.success(response.data.success_message);
        return response;
    }, function (error) {
        NProgress.done();
        if (!!error.response.data.errors) {
            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(error.response.data.errors)) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    toast.error(value);
                }, (+key > 4 ? (+key * 200) : (+ key - 1)));
            }
        } else {```

Comment: ```toast.error(!!error.response.data.error_message ? error.response.data.error_message : error.response.statusText);
        }

        return Promise.reject(error);
    });``` I had to break down the codes.

Comment: Nothing there would make any change to query params. This is not reproducible. In general though, I'd recommend creating a separate instance using `axios.create()` to avoid issues with conflicting interceptors and default configuration

Comment: @Philisonstrike Thanks, I added the interceptors in the question. And thanks for the effort to help me. I appreciate it.